# Continuous integration tool for django project

Tags: django, continuous-integration

We would like to use a continuous integration tool for our `django` project. Would like to know if there are any options which will allow us to run this in a `cloud` environment or locally.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure you must have started using one of the tool, though you can configure [django-jenkins](https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-jenkins) to do Continuous integration.

Here are the configuration steps [documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/kmmbvnr/home/django-jenkins-tutorial). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can use husdon for CI

http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2010/03/08/django-and-hudson-ci-day-1/

Answer (score 0):

Recently I found this one http://travisci.com/, but, in my opinion, $129/month minimal plan is too much.